# c++, how to transfer function that return value to func

Tags: c++, qt, function

so i have class that looks like:

```
class CameraView
{
public:
CameraView(QImage viewImage);
QImage GetView() const;
double Getf() const;


void SetF(double value);


protected:
    double f, c;

QImage ViewImage;
};
```

cpp:

```
   CameraView::CameraView(QImage viewImage){
    this->ViewImage = viewImage;
}

QImage CameraView::GetView() const{
    return this->ViewImage;
}
```

and i want to get GetView In function show. Thereby i need to transfer QImage of instance of class CameraView to function show.

```
void MainWindow::Show(QImage const *img,QGraphicsView *view){

QGraphicsScene *tempImg = new QGraphicsScene ();
tempImg->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*img));

view->setScene(tempImg);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QImage RIImg("/root/Desktop/label.jpg");
CameraView view(RIImg);
//error
this->Show(&(view.GetView()), ui->NormalImg);///
}
```

I need to solve the problem pretty good, so the way where we equate Instance of QImage to view.GetView() and that instance transfer to function Show() looks terrible please anyone on this site know how we can decide with it?

Comment: you will need to pass an Instance of CameraView into Show

Comment: not quite clear. What value do you want to transfer to what function? You know that functions can take parameters, right?

Comment: In your `MainWindow::Show` function, you need to create an instance of `CameraView` in order to execute `CameraView::GetView`.  See function `MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()`.

Comment: `GetView` returns `QImage`. `Show` wants `QImage*` see the problem now?

Comment: @tobi303:  The issue is that `on_pushButton_clicked()` is an event handler and its interface can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `CameraView` member to your `MainWindow` class.

BTW, you would be able to access it without the `this->` syntax:

```
class MainWindow
{
 // ...
  CameraView m_camera_view;
};

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  QImage RIImg("/root/Desktop/label.jpg");
  CameraView m_camera_view(RIImg);
  Show(m_camera_view.GetView(), ui->NormalImg);///
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned above: `GetView` returns `QImage`. `Show` wants `QImage*`

Comment: /root/Desktop/QTprogramms/image_ex/AffinTransf/mainwindow.cpp:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘CameraView::CameraView()’
     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
                          ^

Comment: Your error means you need to implement a default constructor.  Another option is to use a shared pointer and dynamically allocate in the `on_pushButton_clicked` method.